# gdb seeing disassembly at seg fault

Tags: gdb

I have a program that is seg faulting and I reproduce in gdb as follows:

```
$ gdb myprogram

(gdb) run mycmdlineargs

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

If I type:

```
(gdb) list
```

it shows me the source code line where the seg fault occurs, but I would like to see the disassembly (preferably annotated with source code).  What command can I use to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `disassemble` command.